# MSACCESS: How to update a memo field with large text

Tags: ms-access, memo

I've got a **memo** field in MS Access 2010 and I'm trying to paste a large piece of text in it (about 160k chars).

When I paste directly in the table I get an error that "the text is too long to be edited".
The same thing happens when trying to do it via a form.

I've also tried to save the text to a file and the to read the file contents with VBA and then update the table by running a UPDATE table sql statement.  In this case I get a runtime error 3035 that "System resource exceeded".

According to this [post](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/use-a-memo-field-to-store-large-amounts-of-information-70d60485-e4ba-4583-bb67-c2bb6283535a)I should be able to store 1GB of data 
How can I update a memo field with my text otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recordsets to update the field. That way, you won't exceed the maximum length of an update query

(incomplete code, need more details to write more exact code)

```
Dim str As String
'Read text file into str
Dim rs As DAO.RecordSet
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MyTable")
rs.AddNew
rs.Fields("MyMemoField").Value = str
rs.Update
rs.Close
```